# How to hide System.Drawing line with condition

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

How to hide System.Drawing line with condition:

```
    System.Drawing.Pen myPen;            
    myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.White);           
    System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();

    formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 108, 272, 153, 160);  

    myPen.Dispose();
    formGraphics.Dispose();
```

I want to hide the drawn line `formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 108, 272, 153, 160);` with condition `if (x > 1) {} else if (x = 1) {}` display it again

Comment: Don't use CreateGraphics since that's temporary — use the graphics from the container's paint event.  To erase a line, redraw everything but the line.

Comment: If you're in winforms, you should be drawing these repeatedly in the `Form.Paint` event, so just refresh and in the event, don't draw the line this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the `Form.Paint` event, either through the designer or in the form constructor.  Then in the paint event handler do the conditional drawing.  Also make your x variable into a property (public or private) and call `Invalidate` on the form when it changes.  This will cause the form to be redrawing, calling the paint event.

```
private int x = 0;

public int X
{
    get
    {
        return x;
    }

    set
    {
        x = value;
        // Cause the form to be redrawn.
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);

    // Only draw the line if x == 1.
    if (x == 1)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, 108, 272, 153, 160);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, but if I want hide and drown this same line each time if x = 1 drown, if x = 0 hide, then again if x = 1 drown etc. for same line with sequential x switching of 1 and 0

Comment: See edits: call Invalidate on the form when x changes.

Comment: very good solution, exactly what I need, thank you! seems like I need only  public int X Ivalidate